# Azure pipeline issue running databricks workspace import_dir

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, databricks, azure-cli

I'm having an issue with a DevOps pipeline when trying to import notebooks to databricks. Using Azure CLI and Bash, here is the code:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel databricks-cli==0.11.0
      DatabricksUrl='$(workspaceUrl)'
      dapiToken='$(devops-pat-uat)'
      changedCode='$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Code\Databricks'
      
      databricks configure --token <<EOF
      ${DatabricksUrl}
      ${dapiToken}
      EOF

      databricks workspace import_dir -o "$changedCode" "/Shared"
```

Error:
{'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE', 'message': "Path (C:/Program Files/Git/) doesn't start with '/'"}

I'm not sure why the path is changing from "/Shared" to "C:/Program Files/Git/Shared". Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

> Azure pipeline issue running databricks workspace import_dir

According to the error message:

> "Path (C:/Program Files/Git/) doesn't start with '/'"}

Please try to add an extra "`/`" to the code:

```
databricks workspace import_dir -o "$changedCode" "//Shared"
```

Comment: Thank you, it is now working. I did try that before but without the quotes and it did not work.

Comment: @tdumont, How about the result if you add the command line `cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` before the latest last command `databricks workspace import_dir -o "$changedCode" "//Shared"` ?